I have to manually refresh my page for my navbar (which is a client component) to show the ui changes in NextJS
I have a sign in button in my navbar component. I want it to only show if the user has signed in. The checks would be done using session hooks.
But now, I need to manually refresh the page in order to see the changes. For example, when i signed in into the web app through the page /auth/login, the middleware will redirect to /config/profile. But the navbar will still not change the ui: the sign in button will still be showing.
I tried to use useEffect, onclick = () => router.push as well as router.reload and router.refresh but nothing works. They dont seem to refresh the nav bar. I still had to f5 refresh the page manually.
//src/components/main-nav.tsx
//this is the navbar component

"use client"

import * as React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { docsConfig } from "@/config/docs";
import { siteConfig } from "@/config/site";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { LoginButton } from "./auth/login-button";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { UserButton } from "@/components/auth/user-button";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'


export function MainNav() {
    const pathname = usePathname();
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    // Log the current session
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("[main-nav-tsx][session]", { session });
        if (!session) {
            console.log("[main-nav-tsx][session] NO USER SIGNED IN");
        } else {
            console.log("[main-nav-tsx][session] USER SIGNED IN", session.user);
        }
    }, [session]);

    const router = useRouter()

    return (
        <div className="mr-4 hidden md:flex">
            <Link href="/" className="mr-6 flex items-center space-x-2">
                <Icons.logo className="h-6 w-6" />
                <span className="hidden font-bold sm:inline-block">
                    {siteConfig.name}
                </span>
            </Link>
            <nav className="flex items-center gap-4 text-sm lg:gap-6">
                {docsConfig.mainNav?.map((item) =>
                    item.href ? (
                        <Link
                            key={item.href}
                            href={item.href}
                            className={cn(
                                "transition-colors hover:text-foreground/80",
                                pathname === item.href
                                    ? "text-foreground"
                                    : "text-foreground/60"
                            )}
                        >
                            {item.title}
                        </Link>
                    ) : null
                )}
                {/* user button is to be shown only when user is logged in. 
                otherwise, show sign in.
                it works, but it doesnt auto refresh, i have to manually refresh the page */}

                {!session && (
                    <LoginButton>
                        <Button>Sign in</Button>
                    </LoginButton>
                )}

            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}


Additional information that may be useful:
my main-nav is called via site-header, which is called back the root layout.tsx
//src/components/site-header.tsx

import { MainNav } from "@/components/main-nav"
import { MobileNav } from "@/components/mobile-nav"
import { ModeToggle } from "@/components/mode-toggle"
import { SystemStatusPopover } from "./system-status-popover"

export function SiteHeader() {
    return (
        <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 w-full border-b border-border/40 bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
            <div className="container flex h-14 max-w-screen-2xl items-center">
                <MainNav />
                 // other components called...
    )
}

//src/app/layout.tsx

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/theme-provider";
import { SiteHeader } from "@/components/site-header";
import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { auth } from "@/auth";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await auth();
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <ThemeProvider
            attribute="class"
            defaultTheme="system"
            enableSystem
            disableTransitionOnChange
          >
            <SiteHeader />
            {children}
            <Toaster />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}


